# Comparing fields from two different tables in SOQL

Tags: query, relationships

I get this error in output:

> Bind variables only allowed in Apex code'

The query is:

```
   "SELECT O.Id, O.Name, O.OwnerId, U.Name FROM Opportunity as O,User as U WHERE  O.OwnerId = U.Id  "
```

What's wrong with this query?

Comment: what would you like to do? Would you like to test if the logged user is the same of the Opportunity?

Comment: @mPeixoto Yes, and return the owner who creates the opportunity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could write the same SOQL in this way:

```
SELECT ID, Name, OwnerId, Owner.Name
From  Opportunity
```